# Why does an asymetric transfer function cause a non linear group delay?

Tags: filters, infinite-impulse-response, group-delay

I know that an IIR filter exhibits non linear group delay (so different frequencies can be delayed more) and that this is related to the fact that it is asymetric (due to considering previous outputs), but I don't have an intuition for why this would affect different frequencies by differing amounts.

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "asymmetric transfer function"? Also, "non-linear group delay" is probably not what you mean. If the group delay is linear, you still have phase distortions.

Comment: I mean a function is used for the filter that has co-efficients that are not "symetric", so a symetric transfer function would be [0,0,1,0,0] or something. I know that this can't be the case in any IIR filter because the transfer function is not a fixed thing and depends on previous outputs. And I know that this leads to different frequencies in the signal being "delayed" by different amounts which manifests as phase distortion that is different at different frequencies. I just don't have much intuition for WHY this would be the case.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/67526/4298) and its answer?

Comment: @thepman: do you mean an asymmetric impulse response ? The transfer function is the Fourier Transform of the impulse response. As long as the impulse response is real-valued the transfer function will ALWAYS be complex conjugate symmetric (regardless of  FIR, IIR, linear phase, minimum phase, etc)

Comment: Yes, I think so. The coefficients that are applied in the time domain.